# Preset offset for time()

Tags: php, time, offset

A PHP server I use recently changed hosts and now time() is no longer GMT time, which leaves me with a big problem since I rely on it for timezones. The new time is an hour ahead (GMT+1:00).

I could take time() and subtract 86400 but I wanted a way so that from this point, whenever I call time() I get the actual GMT time instead of the ahead time. I am looking for a way to make a "pre set offset" for time().

The closest topic I have found to this question is [Set time offset in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083153/set-time-offset-in-php) and that isn't really related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6208705/2962442 or change timezone in php.ini

Comment: I did not have access to php.ini, but after reading that question using `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon')` seemed to work. I guess I did not change the topic question enough to find pre-answered ones. Thank you!