# How do I find a future date in PHP, only a few days later?

Tags: php

My date() format is m-d-Y and I want to find a future date, say five days from now.
For instance, if my $todays_date is equal to 04-28-2018, I want $future_date to be equal to 05-03-2018 (five days later). Thanks!

Comment: try `(new DateTime())->modify('+5 days')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set time offset in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083153/set-time-offset-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `strtotime()` see below code.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("$date +5 Days"));
$date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
echo $date;
```

Hope this help you.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

Procedural you can use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), and date()

But I prefer using PHP's built in [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class

```
  $Date = new DateTime();
  $Date->modify('+5 days');
  echo $Date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Outputs

```
 2018-05-03
```

You can test it [online here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7fc7597b7999c822c52a4c3c356b7efc295cff77)

This is based of using what is called relative date formats,  you can read all about it in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Using **strtotime**

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));
```

Chained version of Datetime

```
echo (new DateTime())->modify('+5 days')->format('Y-m-d');
```

Both give the same result as the first one, but are only one line.